# Cohomology of Projective Classical Lie Groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, cohomology, rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a compact, connected, simply-connected Lie group with centre $Z(G)$, and consider the Lie group $G/Z(G)$. I believe that for $G$ a classical group, the Lie group $G/Z(G)$ is sometimes called a projective classical group. What is known about the integral cohomology $H^*(G/Z(G);\mathbb{Z})$? I am particularly interested in the integral cohomology of the projective special unitary group $PSU(n)$. I would appreciate any and all references/suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122083/group-cohomology-of-orthogonal-groups-with-integer-coefficient/122103#122103

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ancient history!  I don't remember exactly what is in it, but I think the paper by Paul Baum and William Browder "The cohomology of quotients of classical groups" Topology 3 1965 305–336,
considers the cohomology of these groups.  Of course, even back then, calculations were made in mod $p$ cohomology first, relying on the Bockstein spectral sequence to bootstrap up to integral information.  I don't know of any more recent work that is directly relevant.