# Characteristic classes for general $G$ bundles, not just $G=SO(n)$ or $G=U(n)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

Is there a nice reference where I can get the information of $H^*(BG)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, with $G$ not just $SO$ or $U$ but for example $G=PSU(n)$, $Pin(n)$, $SO(2n)/\{\pm 1\}$,  or $Aut(E_6)$?

I'm happy if I could get the info on the structure of the cohomology up to the degree 4 (as a 4d gauge theorist) or to the degree 10 (as a string theorist.)

Comment: Have a Look at Mimura-Toda "Topology of Lie Groups" or Borel "Topology of Lie groups and characteristic classes." Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 61 (1955), 397–432. 

Comment: See also the references given at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122083/group-cohomology-of-orthogonal-groups-with-integer-coefficient