# Group cohomology of "twisted" projective SU(N) with various coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences, characteristic-classes

Given a group 
$$ 
G= PSU(N) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
where $PSU(N)$ is a projective special unitary group. Say $a \in PSU(N)$, $c \in \mathbb{Z}_2$, then
$$
c a c= a^*,
$$
which $c$ flips $a$ to its complex conjugation written as $a^*$.

> My question is what can we say about the group cohomology of $G= PSU(N) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ with integer coefficient or finite abelian group coefficient? Say
>   $$
> H^k(G, \mathbb{Z})=?
> $$
>   $$
> H^k(G, \mathbb{Z}_2)=?
> $$
>   $$
> H^k(G, \mathbb{Z}_n)=?
> $$
>   Here we can either regard the group cohomology $H^k(G,*)$, or regard it as the topological cohomology of the classifying space of the group $H^k(BG,*)$.
>
> I am ONLY interested in $k=1,2,3,4$. Here $n=2$ or $n=4$ is enough. And when $N$ as an even integer is enough.

---

P.S: For your assitance ---
When $N=2$, I already know that
$$
H^3(SO(3), \mathbb{Z})=H^2(SO(3), \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=H^2(SO(3), \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2.
$$
$$
H^4(SO(3), \mathbb{Z})=H^3(SO(3), \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z},
$$
$$
H^2(PSU(N), \mathbb{Z}_N)=\mathbb{Z}_N,
$$

See a related post: [Group cohomology of orthogonal groups with integer coefficient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122083/group-cohomology-of-orthogonal-groups-with-integer-coefficient)

Comment: Could you include the page of LHS spectral sequence you probably already computed?